# Webform results can not download more than 500 submissions

Tags: 8, webforms

As the title says, I need to download 2600 submissions of one form. The batch runs completely. However, in the download file, I have only the first 500 submissions. 
I have no idea what should I do to debug.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log file? And the Drupal Dblog report?

Comment: Can you increase the max_execution_time?